# Teradata Fastload date format issue

Tags: teradata

I have a flat file which I am trying to load through fastload. The flat file has date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. When I am trying to load it through fastload the records are going in the Error tables. However, when I change the format of date in the flat file as `yyyy-mm-dd` 00:00:00 its loading for that column its loading fine.

```
07/27/2011 00:00:00 -- not working
2011-12-15 00:00:00--working


errlimit 1000000;
tenacity 4;        
sessions 1;
sleep 6;
dateform Ansidate,
```

SET RECORD VARTEXT "|*|" ;
I am taking dateform Ansidate in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSIDATE always expects `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

You need to add a Teradata style typecast in your INSERT using a FORMAT matching your input string:

```
:PROMISE_DTTM(timestamp(0), format 'mm/dd/yyyyBhh:mi:ss')
```

Comment: I tried to do that but again it was redirecting it to error table. below is my Fload script, can you please tell me where should i add:
insert into GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_FETCH_PARTSDWH_ORDER_LN_D ( 
 ORDER_LINE_D_KEY,
 ORDER_HEADER_D_KEY,
 PROMISE_DTTM,
 
) VALUES ( 
 :ORDER_LINE_D_KEY,
 :ORDER_HEADER_D_KEY,
        :PROMISE_DTTM(timestamp(0), format 'yyyy-mm-ddBhh:mi:ss'),

Comment: Ok.. Let me try..will get back to you.Thank you for response :)